# Решение проблем со сборкой программы на Qt

Tags: qt, сборка

Скачал исходники менеджера отчетов БД *eXaro*. Начал устанавливать.
Ему нужен *QtWebKit*. Который у меня в сборке *Qt 4.8.5* отсутсвует.
есть 2 решения:
1) Я ставил через rpm отдельно пакет *libQtWebKit4* но cmake не видел его.  выдавая ошибку `file QWebPage not found`.
2) Взял исходники с полноценным *QtWebKit* (т.к. при сборке скачанного qt с download.qt.io не находил .pro файл для того же *QtWebKit*)  [отсюда](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/qt) и собирал *Qt4.8.5* включая *QtWebKit*. Во время сборки происходят ошибки с *QString*:

```
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpainter.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgraphicsview.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:48,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpainter.h:458:60: error: within this context
     void addTextField(const QRectF &r, const QString &text="", const QString &name="", bool multiLine=false, bool password=false, bool readOnly=false, int maxLength=-1);
                                                            ^
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpainter.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgraphicsview.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:48,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpainter.h:458:84: error: within this context
     void addTextField(const QRectF &r, const QString &text="", const QString &name="", bool multiLine=false, bool password=false, bool readOnly=false, int maxLength=-1);
                                                                                    ^
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpainter.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgraphicsview.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:48,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpainter.h:459:79: error: within this context
     void addCheckBox(const QRectF &r, bool checked=false, const QString &name="", bool readOnly=false);
                                                                               ^
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpainter.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgraphicsview.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:48,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpainter.h:460:64: error: within this context
     void addRadioButton(const QRectF &r, const QString & group="",  bool checked=false, const QString &name="", bool readOnly=false);;
                                                                ^
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpainter.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtGui/qgraphicsview.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:48,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpainter.h:460:109: error: within this context
     void addRadioButton(const QRectF &r, const QString & group="",  bool checked=false, const QString &name="", bool readOnly=false);;
                                                                                                             ^
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpaintengine.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtOpenGL/../../src/opengl/qgl.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtOpenGL/QGLWidget:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:99:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpaintengine.h:175:72: error: within this context
     virtual void addRadioButton(const QRectF &r, const QString & group="", bool checked=false, const QString &name="", bool readOnly=false) {
                                                                        ^
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qstring.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativeview.h:45,
                 from ../../include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativeview.h:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:42:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:597:5: error: ‘QString::QString(const char*)’ is private
     QString(const char *ch);
     ^
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/qpaintengine.h:1:0,
                 from ../../include/QtOpenGL/../../src/opengl/qgl.h:46,
                 from ../../include/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:1,
                 from ../../include/QtOpenGL/QGLWidget:1,
                 from qmlruntime.cpp:99:
../../include/QtGui/../../src/gui/painting/qpaintengine.h:175:116: error: within this context
     virtual void addRadioButton(const QRectF &r, const QString & group="", bool checked=false, const QString &name="", bool readOnly=false) {
                                                                                                                    ^
make[2]: *** [.obj/release-shared/qmlruntime.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/www/qt/tools/qml'
make[1]: *** [sub-qml-make_default-ordered] Ошибка 2
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/www/qt/tools'
make: *** [sub-tools-make_default-ordered] Ошибка 2
```

соответсвенно
1) Можно ли как то заставить *cmake* увидеть *libQt4WebKit*? Я в *cmake* не силен
2) Как исправить ошибку при сборке?

OS: OpenSuse 13.1 если поможет.

UPD: эта ошибка происходит во время сборки файла /tools/qml/qmlruntime.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот [решение](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_27073_0.html), из за определенного макроса QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII в Makefile'ах Qt, в результате чего, в файле /src/corelib/tools/qstring.h конструктор определяется как private: (строки 593-601)

```
private:
#if defined(QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII) && !defined(Q_NO_DECLARED_NOT_DEFINED)
    QString &operator+=(const char *s);
    QString &operator+=(const QByteArray &s);
    QString(const char *ch);
    QString(const QByteArray &a);
    QString &operator=(const char  *ch);
    QString &operator=(const QByteArray &a);
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

для сборки нужно было еще доставить пакет libQtWebKit-devel, а не только библиотеку

Comment: доставлено , не помогло

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?